# Check if Activity is opened by default or coming from an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I am new to Android development.  I am trying to check if my activity is opened by default or if it comes from an intent and if it does to get the extras from it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    protected int firstImageIndex;
    protected String albumName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String comingFrom;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null){
            comingFrom = i.getExtras().getString("comingFrom");
            if (comingFrom.equals("gridView")) {
                albumName = (String) i.getExtras().get("albumName");
                firstImageIndex = i.getExtras().getInt("firstImageIndex");
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            }
        }
        else{
            albumName = "All Photos";
            firstImageIndex = 0;
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    public void openGalleryBucketList(View view) {
        Intent openGalleryIntent = new  Intent(this, GalleryBucketList.class);

        openGalleryIntent.putExtra("sender","First");
        startActivity(openGalleryIntent);
    }

    public void goToLastPhoto(View view) {
        Intent goToLastImageIntent = new Intent(this, LastImageActivity.class);
        goToLastImageIntent.putExtra("firstImageIndex",firstImageIndex);
        goToLastImageIntent.putExtra("albumName", albumName);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the app crashes with a null pointer exception in the line `if(i != null)`

Any help on why and how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

edit: Here is the readout (maybe I am not reading it correctly:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the NPE refers to that line? No dereferencing is attempted there.

Comment: Try `if (comingFrom != null) {`